# Disable alerts in backup exec 2010

Tags: backup, backup-exec, backup-exec-2010

I am trying to disable all alerts in Backup Exec 2010 R3.  I know how to disable each individual ones (tools -> alerts categories), but is there a way to disable them all?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why the heck would you want to do this? Isn't a alert created for the reason to inform you that something important that went wrong?

Comment: @TeXHeX The reasoning is simple, we do backups over the weekend and it fails because there is no one here from IT to acknowledge any alerts.  I was able to disable that alert and I just want to do it for all of them.  We have someone monitor backups M-F.